# guvcview not working with logitech c270 webcam

Tags: drivers, video, webcam, guvcview

I recently purchased a logitech webcam c270 and it works with cheese; however, it doesn't work with guvcview. I completely purged cheese from computer. Then I removed and reinstalled guvcview, but still not working. I've even tried to start from command line. but no luck. Any help appreciated. Thanks
anyway here are the logs. for anyone brave enough... I think I might be missing right driver and/or codecs (video)

```
    jorge@nixbox ~ $ sudo guvcview -d /dev/video0
[sudo] password for jorge: 
guvcview 1.7.1
file guvcview_video.mkv has extension type 1
file guvcview_image.jpg has extension type 0
file guvcview_image.jpg has extension type 0
Video file suffix detected: 1
Image file suffix detected: 0
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
video device: /dev/video0 
Init. UVC Camera (046d:0825) (location: usb-0000:00:04.1-1)
{ pixelformat = 'YUYV', description = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 2/15, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 2/15, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'MJPG', description = 'MJPEG' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'RGB3', description = 'RGB3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'BGR3', description = 'BGR3' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'YU12', description = 'YU12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ pixelformat = 'YV12', description = 'YV12' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 176 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 432, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 544, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 360 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 752, height = 416 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 448 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 800, height = 600 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 864, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 544 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 960, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 576 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1184, height = 656 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 720 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 960 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/25, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
vid:046d 
pid:0825 
driver:uvcvideo
mapping control for Pan (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Tilt (relative)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Pan Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Tilt Reset
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Focus (absolute)
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for LED1 Mode
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for LED1 Frequency
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Disable video processing
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Raw bits per pixel
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: No such file or directory
mapping control for Off
UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
checking format: 1196444237
VIDIOC_G_COMP:: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fps is set to 1/30
drawing controls

fps is set to 1/30
Checking video mode 640x480@32bpp : OK 
 Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
 Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
^CIgnoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
write /home/jorge/.config/guvcview/video0 OK
free controls
cleaned allocations - 100%
Closing portaudio ...OK
Closing GTK... OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system? With 16.04 I can make it works. Try low value for exposition, like:
[image] [image]
I got tons of errors too.

```
:~$ guvcview 
    GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.2
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
    ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
    ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connexion refusée

    ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connexion refusée

    Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Cannot connect to server request channel
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Cannot connect to server request channel
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
    Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Cannot connect to server request channel
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Cannot connect to server request channel
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Cannot connect to server request channel
    jack server is not running or cannot be started
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
    V4L2_CORE: VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS for multiple controls failed (error -1)
    V4L2_CORE: using VIDIOC_S_CTRL for user class controls
    V4L2_CORE: control(0x0098091a) "White Balance Temperature" failed to set (error -1)
    V4L2_CORE: VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS for multiple controls failed (error -1)
    V4L2_CORE: using VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS on single controls for class: 0x009a0000
    V4L2_CORE: control(0x009a0902) "Exposure (Absolute)" failed to set (error -1)
    V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
    V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
    V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
    GUVCVIEW: video codec changed to 0
    GUVCVIEW: video codec changed to 8
    GUVCVIEW: (status) saving image to /home/kx16/my_photo-2.jpg
    GUVCVIEW: (status) saving image to /home/kx16/my_photo-3.jpg
    V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Ressource temporairement non disponible
```